# Pass R object to Python after running R Script

Tags: python, r, object

I have a python script `Test.py` that runs an R script `Test.R` below:

```
import subprocess
import pandas
import pyper


#Run Simple R Code and Print Output
proc = subprocess.Popen(['Path/To/Rscript.exe',
                         'Path/To/Test.R'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```

The R script is below:

```
library("methods")
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
data <- data.frame(x,y)
```

How can I pass the R data frame (or any R object for that matter) to Python?  I've had great difficulty getting `Rpy2` to work on windows, and I've seen this [link](http://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/another-way-to-access-r-from-python-pyper/) to use `PypeR` but it's using a lot of in-line R code in the Python code and I'd really like to keep the code on separate files (or is this practice considered acceptable?)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced issues getting Rpy2 to work on a mac too and use the same workaround calling R directly from python via [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html); also agree that keeping files separate helps manage complexity.

First export your data as a .csv from R (again script called through subprocess):

```
write.table(data, file = 'test.csv')
```

After that, you can import as a python pandas data frame ([Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)):

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

dat
   row  x    y
   1    1    2
   2    2    4
   3    3    6
   4    4    8
   5    5    10
   6    6    12
   7    7    14
   8    8    16
   9    9    18
  10   10    20
```

Comment: Yeah I figured I could export everything to CSV and read to each program that way, I guess I was hoping for a way to do it in code.  Thanks.